# MapReduce for cross-correlating datasets drawn from 100TB of data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have around 100TB of data, where each datum (element) is around 1MB in size.  I also have N regions consisting of M elements drawn from the data.  Every element appears in at most 3 regions.  The M elements within a region must be cross-correlated into an MxM correlation matrix.  I'm not sure of the average size of M exactly, but it can vary from as little as 5 to as large as several hundred.

In our current implementation, we spawn off threads to process each region, and fetch individual elements by reading files over NFS.  It turns out that this solution is I/O bound, and we're now looking at ways of distributing the data and the computation together.  At a glance, MapReduce seems like a good fit for this problem, but I'm not familiar enough with the paradigm to know for sure.

Let's say I went with Hadoop.  My first thought would be to get the data into HDFS as chunks, attempting to make each chunk consist of elements from the same region as best as possible.  Each Map task would then be given a set of elements and emit (region, element) pairs.  Each Reduce task would then get all the elements for a region and perform the cross correlation.  But of course, I'm not sure if this intuitive, and perhaps naive approach is a reasonable use of MapReduce.

For one thing, I'm not sure about the data/computation locality here.  I gather that, in general, the data being processed by some Map task is likely to be located on the same node.  But is that also true for the Reduce tasks?

For example, if I emitted from my Map task a value pointing to some location within a file, are the chances good that the Reduce task is running on the same node?  Would it perhaps be better to read the data into memory in the Map phase, then it emit the 1MB element in some serialized form?  Would that not result in all 100TB of data in RAM or copied to intermediate files?

So, is this a good candidate for MapReduce, or should I be looking elsewhere for solutions?  Is this a good problem for MapReduce, but a poor solution?  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: What does "The M elements within a region must be cross-correlated into an MxM correlation matrix." mean?

Comment: That's the domain-specific goal of the processing.  I only mention it to illustrate that I need to process groups of M elements together.

Comment: OK. That tells me nothing.  You're asking for help with an algorithm that's poorly defined.

Comment: Okay, so say I have a bunch of microphones recording audio.  Now say there are signals coming from different origins.  I want to correlate all the signals from a specific origin picked up by a specific microphone.  The signal in this example is one of the "elements" from above.  The origin-microphone pair defines one of the N regions.  Because it's hard to know exactly where a signal came from, there is some overlap between the regions.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it sounds like you're trying to add the reducer unnecessarily. Assuming N is large enough, I'd try the following: insert each region (1/N of the whole dataset) to a mapper and calculate the cross-correlation matrix there. Since the reducer here isn't actually necessary, you could ignore it completely and write the result of the map-phase straight out. In MapReduce, the heavy lifting is usually done in the map-phase, and in this case it sounds like there's no real need for a reducer if you're only looking for the M cross-correlation matrices.

> I gather that, in general, the data being processed by some Map task is likely to be located on the same node. But is that also true for the Reduce tasks?

Generally reduce tasks require the data (that is, the result of map tasks) to be transferred to them before they can operate on it. It's a good idea to compress the data as much as possible before passing it to the reducer(s) to minimize network traffic.

Comment: So I guess the data would then need to be stored in such a way that it could be split by region instead of by element, right?  That could work.  The only downside I see is that, since elements can appear in up to 3 regions, we could triple the amount of data we're storing.  Add in Hadoop's replication factor, and that's a lot of storage.  We'd also be losing some versatility in using the same input data for other projects.  But still, it may be the way to go.

Comment: In this case one InputSplit would be one region, yes. Granted, it's not an optimal solution if you're looking to minimize storage space.